# Launch an android app by a hardware button

Tags: android

I hope to  build an android application which launches when specific hardware button clicks.(As an example when I press the volume up button for 30 seconds app  must launch without  increasing the volume. ) I want to know is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`. The received intent includes a single extra field `EXTRA_KEY_EVENT` which contains the key event that caused the broadcast. You can use this key event to get which key was pressed and to launch your app. For example, add this to your main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    HardwareButtonReceiver receiver = new HardwareButtonReceiver();

    registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiver);

}

private class HardwareButtonReceiver implements BroadcastReceiver {
     void onReceive(Intent intent) {
          KeyEvent e = (KeyEvent) intent.getExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT); 
          if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
              launchApp();
          }
     } 
}

private void launchApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExampleActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Replace `ExampleActivity.class` with the name of your main activity.

Comment: @tabapp : Thank you so much for your help.Can you explain the implementation part of onCreate method in MainActivity.java file .

Comment: @hasitha1990 No problem. I have updated the answer to make it clearer how to implement this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @tabapp .Basically I tried to  pop up a toast when I press the volume up button . I have given my code below.