# How to open flutter app in background using volume or power button double press?

Tags: flutter, button, background

I am tried to make an app for security issues. I wish when users press the power or volume button 2 times my app will open immediately in the background and doing its task. Now how to implement those things using flutter?

Answer (score 0):

For now, you need to write some native code. You can have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22590261/10659482) for Android.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not possible to implement using flutter? if added those code for android how works it on ios? I wish my app will works continually on both android and ios.